# Word for Company Grounds

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes the entire region of land on which a company or organization resides. For example:

"Make sure to not smoke any cigarettes while on Boeing's ___!"

I've heard the term **campus** being used to this effect, but this has the inherent problem of being ambiguous: is Boeing perhaps a university, then?

Are there any alternatives? *Headquarters* isn't the connotation I'm necessarily trying to convey, and the phrase "Boeing's *grounds*" just sounds awkward.

Answer (score 6):

While *campus* is normally defined as "the grounds and buildings of a university, college, or school", M-W Unabridged notes that *campus* can generally be used to refer to "any grounds that resemble a campus."

Large tech companies like Intel, Microsoft, and the like often use *campus* to refer to their premises, e.g., "Intel's Folsom campus is the largest in California."

So saying something like

> Make sure to not smoke any cigarettes while on Boeing's campus.

is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: +1 *Campus* is used in many contexts besides that of a university... especially when talking about the "grounds" of a private sector company.

Comment: Definitely the right answer. Despite the OP's fears, it's highly unlikely to cause any ambiguity - even if you don't already know what Boeing is (unlikely if you're on Boeing's campus), you could work out from context what's intended.

Answer (score 3):

The word I would use would be ***premises***.

OED sense 3b of *premises*.

In pl. In extended use. A house or building together with its grounds, outhouses, etc., esp. a building or part of a building that houses a business. Now also occas. with sing. concord.

Comment: This is correct but i think a lot of people would take "premises" to mean "inside the building/buildings", so the No Smoking sign might not work as well as you'd hope.

Comment: @Max Williams 1   I will attach OED sense 3b, to my answer. It accords entirely with my own understanding.

Comment: I wasn't saying that's not correct,(I said it **was** correct), i just meant that a lot of people **don't know** that premises includes the outdoor area, so that you would have a lot of conversations like "Excuse me, smoking's not allowed on company premises." "I'm not in the premises, i'm outside".  "Actually premises includes the outdoor area."  "Are you sure?  I thought it just meant inside".  "Sigh (reaches for dictionary").

Answer (score 2):

You could use "Site", which includes the indoor and outdoor areas, although this tends to be associated with building works.

Answer (score 1):

The only word that came to my mind was compound.

Boeing's **compound**:

```
ˈkɒmpaʊnd/
noun
noun: compound; plural noun: compounds

an open area enclosed by a fence, for example around a factory or large house or within a prison.
```

I was looking for a way to link google's definition, as it includes it way deep in it.
If anyone can help me with editing it, feel free!

Comment: The downside of *compound* is that it has connotations of a closed-off, self-contained area, which doesn't necessarily describe the open, landscaped office parks that characterize many large companies' facilities today. When *compound* appears on the news in these parts, it is invariably some sort of dangerous quasi-fortress: a prison, a white separatist camp, a cult settlement. Then again, who am I to say a corporation's offices never feel like any of those three?

Comment: I agree, "compound" sounds like somewhere that is heavily secured, like an army base.

Answer (score 1):

I would say "Make sure to not smoke any cigarettes while on Boeing property," changing the possessive to an adjective. But to my ears, "Boeing's grounds" sounds perfectly OK. Also, "campus" usually does mean a university, but Boeing itself call its grounds a "campus" (http://www.boeing.com/assets/pdf/commercial/aviationservices/flight-services/training/seattle_siteguide_12_9.pdf), and this is not uncommon (http://www.janssen.com/us/contact-us, for another example).

Comment: I think property is the best suggestion, as it's not an unusual use of a word (unlike campus) and everyone would intuitively know that you meant the indoors **and** outdoors parts.